# MaxMind GeoLite mysql vs binary dat performance

Tags: performance, geoip, maxmind

I am wondering if there is any huge performance difference choosing binary dat and using MaxMind php api vs importing GeoLite csv into mysql database and using database.

dat format is 20 MB and it needs reading it from disk every time. It will be included in Magento extension and it will run also on sites hosted on sharing host servers.

Comment: This is a good question... i'm about to either install the mysql version or run the .dat file.. probably will go mysql...

Answer (score 0):

The PHP API is really fast, I haven't tested MySQL lookups, but I'd expect them to come in much slower. MySQL is remarkably fast to connect, but you're still connecting & then parsing & optimizing the query.

We did some testing, and found the Apache Extension, PHP Extension, and (surprisingly) the PHP Library to be very fast. No real perf hit when installing them. Details are available in our [blog post](https://wonderproxy.com/blog/performance-of-geoip-apache-extension-vs-php/).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @preinheimer that MySQL lookups are slower than using the Maxmind mmdb file.

However, I do want to point out that Maxmind lookup is fastest specifically when you are using the C-compiled libmaxminddb.so PHP extension. In fact, in my read tests I compared MySQL, SQLite, and MMDB, and MySQL was about 3.5 times slower, and SQLite was eaxctly 2 times slower when compared to MMDB lookup using the extension.

When using pure PHP library, without the extension, it is faster than MySQL, but slower than SQLite (by about 3 times).

Also, MMDB files are considerably smaller than SQLite or MySQL databases, if space is a concern. I have also experienced high load on MySQL server, where the lookups became increasingly slower, which is not an issue with the mmdb file. Reading mmdb file is less resource intensive than using MySQL.

SQLite does not have MySQL issues as far as resource usage, so as a backup option it's a solid option. However the database file size may be a concern.